How do calls of models.Manager and custom managers work?
The following question was asked by a different user that subsequently removed the question. But I think it is useful to "dig" a bit in how Django's manager logic works.

I extended the models.Manager class and created a custom manager.
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status=Post.Status.PUBLISHED)
It's more than understandable, BUT how do calls of managers work?
objects = models.Manager()  # The default manager.
published = PublishedManager()  # Our custom manager.
I don't address get_queryset() method, I just call constructors.
Then how does it work?


I feel that you should have ideally tried to get a few people to undelete that original question, although mentioning that the question was originally posted by another user and quoting it follows the attribution requirement, that added notice feels a bit weird to have in the question.

@AbdulAzizBarkat: I did, I flagged it twice, and both got declined, and said I should repost the question. The user was removed by moderators IIRC after some angry comments.

It looks like the question was deleted by the user themselves according to the deletion notice, from what I understand moderators probably won't undelete it and leave it to SME's to decide that.

@AbdulAzizBarkat: yes the OP deleted the question (almost) immediately after receiving an answer. Then asked some extra question, and got quite upset, so the moderators removed the account, and did not want to undelete the question. FWIW, the flags raised and answers: https://pastebin.com/3iGzZMjK

It does not need to, the .all() [Django-doc], .get(…) [Django-doc], etc. all behind the curtains call get_queryset() and then perform that method on the result [GitHub]:

class BaseManager:
    # ...
    
    @classmethod
    def _get_queryset_methods(cls, queryset_class):
        def create_method(name, method):
            @wraps(method)
            def manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

            return manager_method

        new_methods = {}
        for name, method in inspect.getmembers(
            queryset_class, predicate=inspect.isfunction
        ):
            # Only copy missing methods.
            if hasattr(cls, name):
                continue
            # Only copy public methods or methods with the attribute
            # queryset_only=False.
            queryset_only = getattr(method, "queryset_only", None)
            if queryset_only or (queryset_only is None and name.startswith("_")):
                continue
            # Copy the method onto the manager.
            new_methods[name] = create_method(name, method)
        return new_methods


This inspects the methods of the queryset class it will wrap. Now if the QuerySet has a method .all(), it will create a small function .all() for the manager, that first calls the get_queryset() of the manager, and then .all() on the queryset. It does that for all functions defined in the queryset class, and thus creates for each a function for the manager.
These are then injected as members in the Manager with [GitHub]:

class BaseManager:
    # ...
    
    @classmethod
    def from_queryset(cls, queryset_class, class_name=None):
        if class_name is None:
            class_name = "%sFrom%s" % (cls.__name__, queryset_class.__name__)
        return type(
            class_name,
            (cls,),
            {
                "_queryset_class": queryset_class,
                **cls._get_queryset_methods(queryset_class),
            },
        )


But there is something else that plays here: how does the manager knows what the model is? Django's models call .contribute_to_class(…) on every attribute in the class, if it is available, for a manager, that looks like [GitHub]:

class BaseManager:
    # ...
    
    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        self.name = self.name or name
        self.model = cls

        setattr(cls, name, ManagerDescriptor(self))

        cls._meta.add_manager(self)


This thus injects the model into the manager, which was not even known at the time you constructed the item. It does not sett the manager itself on the model class, but a descriptor of it.
The descriptor then will [delegate getting the attribute to the manager:

class ManagerDescriptor:
    # ...

    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        if instance is not None:
            raise AttributeError(
                "Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % cls.__name__
            )

        if cls._meta.abstract:
            raise AttributeError(
                "Manager isn't available; %s is abstract" % (cls._meta.object_name,)
            )

        if cls._meta.swapped:
            raise AttributeError(
                "Manager isn't available; '%s' has been swapped for '%s'"
                % (
                    cls._meta.label,
                    cls._meta.swapped,
                )
            )

        return cls._meta.managers_map[self.manager.name]


This will prevent that you can use my_book.objects, and thus only use Book.objects, and also prevents calling the manager on an abstract models.
